# Finding a string using "in" in a larger string

Tags: python, string, list, find

I want to check the existence of a string "cde" in a larger string "abcde".
Due to flexibility of Python, the following works.

```
>>> 'cde' in 'abcde'
True
```

This is too good, and I wonder why it should work. My confusion comes from the following.

First, a string in python is not a list, although it provides a convenient conversion like the following.

```
>>> 'abcde'[1]
'b'
```

But they are different.

```
>>> 'abcde' == list('abcde')
False
```

Second, if I make a list using "in" the string is made one by one as follows.

```
>>> [x for x in 'abcde']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

But magically, the above code finds a multiple characters 'cde' at once in 'abcde'.

Comment: I'm confused by this question.  What does a list have to do with substring matching?  The `__contains__` method for strings vs. lists serves two very different purposes.

Comment: `'cde' in 'abcde'` is a totally different use of `in` from `x for x in 'abcde'`; one is checking containment, the other is looping. It's unclear to me what you think the link is.

Comment: The keyword `in` can have different behavior depending on context.

Comment: @user3483203 you ar right. Strictly speaking it is not related. I don't understand how "in" works and I don't know how to formulate the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's what I want to understand. So in the strict sense, they are different commands?

Comment: Yes, one is an operator https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations the other is part of a compound statement https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reserved word `in` can be used in three different places, the official place to look is the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) but this might be awkward if you're getting started.  the places are:

1. in a [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)
2. in comprehensions, like [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) but they can be used with `set`s and `dict`s as well
3. as a [comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#not-in)